# Sum of infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n-1}{n!}t^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this problem, finding infinite sum of this series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n-1}{n!}t^n$$

It should be done using derivatives and integrals, like for example:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t}s^nds=\int_{0}^{t}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^nds=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{1-s}ds=-ln(1-t)$$

I have some ideas on how the solution should be found, but this $(-1)^n$ is keeping me confused, I don't know what should I do with it.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ldots =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n!} (-t)^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(-t)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!} (-t)^{n}  -e^{-t}=(-t) e^{-t} - e^{-t}.$$

Comment: Very useful solving the $(-1)^n$ problem, many many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I have one more question looking at this: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n!} (-t)^n$$

Isn't it: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n!} (-t)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n(n-1)!} (-t)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!} (-t)^n$$

In other words, why is in your solution used $n=1$ index?

Comment: Well, the $0$the term is $0$ so you can start with $n=1$. And be carefull with $(-1)$ factorial..